# Connect issue using IPv6 on Unity3D UNET server

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am deploying dedicated server made on `UNET` and when I start server I try to get list of all IPs (both `IPv4` and `IPv6`). My server is deployed on a `Linux` server on `DigitalOcean` with IPv6 support enabled, server can be pinged via IPv6 address.

When I connect via IPv4 from client to server (from `NetworkClient` to `NetworkServer`) - everything works fine, however, when I connect via IPv6 - I get `timeout error`. Strange thing is that it seems to work fine on Windows server (I can connect via IPv6), but doesn't work on Linux.

I am using `Unity 5.3`. And when I try `DNS.GetHostEntry(hostName)` I get my IPv4 addresses as usual, but IPv6 addresses are returned to me in format `"::"`, like from `IPAddress.IPv6Any` field, but I see them in correct format when I get ipconfig on server.

Can anybody help me out with this issue?

Comment: Seems like a bug in .Net, not in Unity :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's support for **IPv6** begins with 5.3.4p4. Please check your patch version. try to update your patch with at-least 5.3.4p4